# What is the difference between a Label and a LinkLabel in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms

The two both appear in the toolbar and I was just wondering what the difference between the two were. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A link label is like a hyperlink that you'd see on a webpage. It's a label thats blue and has an underline and, when clicked, can point to a URL. A label is just a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LinkLabel control is a label control that can display a *hyperlink*. A LinkLabel control is inherited from the *Label* class so it has all the functionality provided by the Windows Forms Label control.

LinkLabel control does not participate in *user input or capture mouse or keyboard events*.

Answer (score 0):

LinkLabel is a hyperlink label that can have a navigatable endpoint- [MSDN article for LinkLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx)